# What is the stance of magic users towards Vampires?

Tags: lore, shadowrun

The rules states that vampires, and all the subspecies, feed upon the very Essence of their prey. Since your Essence score influences your Magic and Resonance attributes, and loosing Essence by any means mean that your Magic or Resonance gets lowered definitively unless you spend XP, since it doesn't regenerate naturally, one would expect magic-users to be very wary of vampires-type, or outright hunt them as a precaution. But I couldn't find anything definitive on the various supplements that I've read.

So, what is the official in-universe stance of magic-users (I include metasapients with natural magical abilities in this term, even if it's just dual-natured for example) towards vampire and their subspecies?

Comment: Are you interested in the longer lore or SR5 only?

Comment: @Trish The longer lore, although with as many information on SR5 that you have since we'll be playing in that time period.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## They despise and fear them.

But they are not alone in this. Everyone else does too.

Vampires and such all suffer from a strain of HMHVV. And they are uniformly feared and despised by the average person in the 6th world. There are exceptions to this but those are mostly bound to a particular location like the ghoul nation in Africa.

The advantage that vampires and other HMHVV I infected have is that they are a lot less obvious then sufferers of the ghoul strain (HMHVV III/Krieger strain).

Both the CAS and the UCAS have a ghoul bounty of 1500 nuyen which is issued by the state. This covers any kind of HMHVV carrier and is in general a good way for shadow runners strapped for work to augment their income.

Thanks [Trish](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/30306/trish) for the following references:

SR4 Running Wild p64 did list this and the SR4 Runners Companion had a column about this in the HMHVV chapter.

And thanks [guildsbounty](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/16358/guildsbounty) for finding this 5e reference

> Many metroplexes offer bounties on Infected, and the price paid for a live specimen is worth it for those who won’t feel a twinge of guilt at the thought of the torturous experiments that will be performed on them.
> -- SR5's Run Faster (p128)